# Haskell: Generate an array out of multiple maybes

Tags: haskell

I have simple question but I can't find an elegant solution.
I have a function like this:

```
getFoos :: Maybe Int
        -> Maybe Int
        -> Maybe Int
        -> [(String, Int)]
getFoos ma mb mc = ...
```

I would like to create this array: `[("A": 1), ("B": 2), ("C": 3)]`.
But that's only if the three arguments are Just! If one or several are Nothing, they will simply not appear in the resulting array.
Any elegant way to accomplish this?

For info, the real signature of my function is:

```
 getQuerySelect :: Maybe Token
                -> Maybe DeviceId
                -> Maybe SensorId
                -> Maybe Int
                -> Maybe Int
                -> Maybe Int
                -> Maybe UTCTime
                -> Maybe UTCTime
                -> [(String, String)]
```

It's meant for database query with MongoDB.

My design so far:

```
  getQuerySelect mdev msen ... = do
  let selDev = [("device_id", dev) | (Just (DeviceId dev)) <- [mdev]]
  let selSen = [("sensor_id", sen) | (Just (SensorId sen)) <- [msen]]
  ...
  return $ selDev <> selSen <> ...
```

Works, but still a bit awkward in my opinion.

Comment: Did you mean `[("A", a), ("B", b), ("C", c)]`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz exactly, corrected

Comment: I think your question should be you have Maybe a, Maybe b, Maybe c and you want to transform it to Maybe (a, b, c)? but the difficult part the inner type are heterogenous and you want them to be scaled well?

Comment: The most easier one is just to use pattern matching like
`getQuerySelect (Just token) (Just deviceId) .... = Just (token, deviceId)` `getQuerySelect _ _ .... = Nothing`

If they are honogenous list, you could just use `traverse id` to change [Maybe a] to Maybe [a].

Comment: @bruteforcecat No, the result type is `[(String, String)]`. Each "Just" argument will be analysed and put into the result array. Arguments equal to "Nothing" will simply be not included in the result list.

Comment: Why not introduce a type `(Maybe Token, Maybe DevideId, Maybe SensorId, Maybe Int, Maybe Int, Maybe Int, Maybe UTCTime, Maybe UTCTime)` together with a type  `(Token, DevideId, SensorId, Int, Int, Int, UTCTime, UTCTime)` .

Comment: @Elmex80s good idea, I would call this type "QueryParams"... That would make the signature shorter. However, I'm not sure how that solves the problem?

Comment: A question is, do you really want an array/list or is a tuple good enough. Makes a huge difference to your (final) solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to "scale well for more Maybes", then just work with an array in the first place:

```
getFoosArr :: [Maybe Int] -> [(String, Int)]
```

The implementation could then be e.g.:

```
getFoosArr = catMaybes . zipWith (\a -> fmap (a,)) [A..]
```

First we tag each `Maybe Int` with a letter<sup>1</sup>, and then it's just a matter of filtering out the `Just`s with `catMaybes`.

And of course your original function would simply need to pass the arguments then:

```
getFoos ma mb mc = getFoosArr [ma, mb, mc]
```

---

If you have heterogenous types, but want to convert it all to `String` anyway, it's easy; make `getFoosArr` take `[Maybe String]`, and convert the `Just`s before passing further:

```
getFoosHet ma mb mc = getFoosArr 
                      [ fmap showA ma
                      , fmap showB mb
                      , fmap showC mc
                      ]
```

I'm assuming `showA :: A -> String`, `ma :: Just A`.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've eta-reduced `\a b -> fmap (a,) b` to `\a -> fmap (a,)`. It could also be written as `fmap . (,)`, but I personally find it a bit less readable.

Comment: Thanks, I added some context to my question to explain what I meant by "scale well for more Maybes"... Actually they are a bit heterogeneous.

Comment: @cdupont How do you convert the inner types to `String`? Just `show`?

Comment: some types might need some transformation (formating for UCTTime etc.). So having one line per Maybe and accumulate the results is good enough...

Comment: Then convert beforehand, each specifically; I'll add that to the answer.